# Error: 401: Bot Token is required - Telegram - Telegraf

Tags: node.js, typescript, bots, telegram, prisma

I'm making a bot for the betting platform: **blaze.com**
who sends betting signals to **telegram**
but it's giving an error in the **token**, even though I put the token in the **.env**, it's not working! who can **help me**?

> **.env.example**

```
PORT = 3000
TOKEN = #####################
CHANNEL_NAME = -1772325150

DATABASE_URL="mysql://userDatabase:password@localhost:port/nameDatabase"
```

> **CreateBot.ts**

```
import { Telegraf } from "telegraf"
import { ConfigsController } from "../useCases/configs/ConfigsController"
import { ConfigsUseCase } from "../useCases/configs/ConfigsUseCase"
import { CountsUseCase } from "../useCases/counts/CountsUseCase"



interface IMessage {
    countGreen?: number
    countRed?: number
    color?: string
    message: string
}

interface IDataCount {
    id: string
    countWhite: number
    countGreen: number
    countRed: number
    countGale1: number
    countGale2: number
    totalWin?: number
    totalSent?: number
    percentageWin?: number
}

class Bot {
    start: string
    bots: Telegraf

    constructor() {
        this.start = "Bot On! "
        this.bots = new Telegraf (process.env.TOKEN)
    }

    public async inital() {

        try {
            this.bots.launch();

            process.once("SIGINT", () => this.bots.stop("SIGINT"));
            process.once("SIGTERM", () => this.bots.stop("SIGTERM"));
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("Error in connection of API!")
        }
    }

    async sendMessage({ countGreen, countRed, color, message }: IMessage) {
        try {
            const messageId = await this.bots.telegram.sendMessage(process.env.CHANNEL_NAME, message, { parse_mode: 'HTML' })

            return messageId.message_id
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("Error send message!")
        }

    }

    async deleteMessageWithID(messageID: any) {
        try {
            await this.bots.telegram.deleteMessage(process.env.CHANNEL_NAME, messageID)
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("Error in delete message!")
        }
    }

    async commandBot() {
        this.bots.start(async (ctx) => {
            await ctx.reply(` Bem vindo ao ${ctx.botInfo.first_name} \n\n/padrao Ver as configurações do Bot.\n\n/config Cadastrar e alterar as configs do Bot.\n\n/resultado Envia relatório no canal.\n<i>Você pode passar uma data\nExemplo: '24/01/2022', se não vai\nser enviado com a data do dia.</i>\n\n/help Ajuda.`, { parse_mode: 'HTML' })
        })

        this.bots.help(async (ctx) => {
            await ctx.reply(` Bot Comandos \n\n/padrao Ver as configurações do Bot.\n\n/config Cadastrar e alterar as configs do Bot.\n\n/resultado Envia relatório no canal.\n<i>Você pode passar uma data\nExemplo: '24/01/2022', se não vai\nser enviado com a data do dia.</i>`, { parse_mode: 'HTML' })
        })

        this.bots.command("padrao", async (ctx) => {
            const configUseCase = new ConfigsUseCase()
            const configs = await configUseCase.show()

            if (configs !== null) {
                const { activo, standard } = await configUseCase.show()
                await ctx.reply(` Bot Configs ⚙️\n\n<b>Bot:</b> ${activo ? "Ativado" : "Desativado"}\n<b>Padrão:</b> ${Number(standard)}`, { parse_mode: 'HTML' })
                return
            }
            await ctx.reply(`Você precisa configurar seu bot\n\n/config`, { parse_mode: 'HTML' })
        })

        this.bots.command("resultado", async (ctx) => {
            const [command, date] = ctx.message.text.split(" ")
            const countUseCase = new CountsUseCase()
            const data = await countUseCase.getCounts(date)

            if (data.length === 0) {
                console.log("Sem registro")
                await ctx.reply(` Resultados até agora! \n\n⛔<b>Sem registro</b>\n\n✅Acertos: <b>0</b>\n❌Não Bateu: <b>0</b>\n\nPrimeira Entrada: <b>0</b>\n1️⃣Primeira Gale: <b>0</b>\n2️⃣Segunda Gale: <b>0</b>\n⚪Winn Branco: <b>0</b>\n\n <b>0% de aproveitamento!</b>`, { parse_mode: 'HTML' })
                return
            }

            const { greenWhite, green, red, gale1, gale2, totalWin, totalSent, percentageWin } = await this.calculateCounts(data)

            const message = ` Resultados até agora! \n\n✅Acertos: <b>${totalWin}</b>\n❌Não Bateu: <b>${red}</b>\n\nPrimeira Entrada: <b>${green}</b>\n1️⃣Primeira Gale: <b>${gale1}</b>\n2️⃣Segunda Gale: <b>${gale2}</b>\n⚪Winn Branco: <b>${greenWhite}</b>\n\n <b>${Math.round(100 - percentageWin)}% de aproveitamento!</b>`
            await this.sendMessage({ message })
            await ctx.replyWithHTML(` <b>Relatório enviado!</b>`)
            return
        })

        this.bots.command("config", async (ctx) => {
            const configUseCase = new ConfigsUseCase()
            const configs = await configUseCase.show()

            const configsController = new ConfigsController()

            const respone = ctx.message.text.split(" ")
            const [_, botName, password, newDefault, activo] = ctx.message.text.split(" ")
            const newActivo = activo === "ativado" ? true : false

            if (respone.length !== 5) {
                await ctx.reply("⚠️ <b>Parametros Errados!</b>\n\nEnviar da seguinte maneira:\n\n<b>Comando:</b> /config\n<b>Bot:</b> nome do seu bot\n<b>Senha:</b> senha de acesso\n<b>Padrão:</b> número do seu padrão, ex. 3\n<b>Ativo:</b> ativado ou desativado\n\n<b>Exemplo:</b> /config blaze-bot abc123 4 ativado", { parse_mode: 'HTML' })
                return
            }

            switch (activo) {
                case "ativado":
                case "desativado":
                    if (configs === null) {
                        await configsController.create({ name: botName, standard: Number(newDefault), activo: newActivo, password: password.toString() })
                        await ctx.reply(`⚠️ Atenção ⚠️\n\nCadastro realizado!`, { parse_mode: 'HTML' })
                        return
                    }

                    if (configs.password === password && configs.name === botName) {
                        await configsController.create({ name: botName, standard: Number(newDefault), activo: newActivo, password: password.toString() })
                        await ctx.reply(`⚠️ Atenção ⚠️\n\nParâmetros Alterados\n\n<b>Bot:</b> ${newActivo ? "Ativado" : "Desativado"}\n<b>Padrão:</b> ${Number(newDefault)}`, { parse_mode: 'HTML' })
                        return
                    }
                    await ctx.reply(`⚠️ Atenção ⚠️\n\nNome do Bot ou Senha errada!`, { parse_mode: 'HTML' })
                    break;
                default:
                    await ctx.reply("⚠️ Atenção ⚠️\n\nInforme se o BOT está \n<b>ativado</b> ou <b>desativado</b>", { parse_mode: 'HTML' })
                    break;
            }
        })
    }

    async calculateCounts(data: Array<IDataCount>) {
        let greenWhite = null
        let green = null
        let red = null
        let gale1 = null
        let gale2 = null

        data.forEach(async counts => {
            greenWhite = greenWhite + counts.countWhite
            green = green + counts.countGreen
            red = red + counts.countRed
            gale1 = gale1 + counts.countGale1
            gale2 = gale2 + counts.countGale2
        })
        let totalWin = green + greenWhite + gale1 + gale2
        let totalSent = totalWin + red
        let percentageWin = Math.round((red * 100) / totalSent)

        return {
            greenWhite,
            green,
            red,
            gale1,
            gale2,
            totalWin,
            totalSent,
            percentageWin
        }
    }
}

export { Bot }
```

I already changed the bot token and it still won't:

[image]

Comment: Creating a .env file doesn't automatically load values that are in it. Are you using something like `dotenv` ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't need the answer anymore, but anyway

To make ***.env*** work, you have to install something like ***dotenv*** https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv

*npm install dotenv --save*

```
require('dotenv').config()

// or

import * as dotenv from 'dotenv' // see https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv#how-do-i-use-dotenv-with-import
dotenv.config()
```

It loads environment variables from an ***.env file*** into ***process.env***, so in your case,

```
this.bots = new Telegraf (process.env.TOKEN)
```

doesn't work, because it can't get data from ***process.env***